# React Material UI Table - Switches all toggle at the same time

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I have added a react mat ui table to my app and added switches into one of the columns but for some reason they all toggle together rather than independently.

How can I change this?

```js
  <TableBody>
            {operators.map((row) => (
              <TableRow key={row.key}>
                <TableCell component="th" scope="row">
                  {row.operator}
                </TableCell>
                <TableCell>
                  <Typography component="div">
                    <Grid
                      component="label"
                      container
                      alignItems="center"
                      // justify="flex-end"
                      spacing={1}
                    >
                      <Grid item>Off</Grid>
                      <Grid item>
                        <AntSwitch
                          checked={checkboxState.checkedC}
                          onChange={handleChange}
                          name="checkedC"
                        />
                      </Grid>
                      <Grid item>On</Grid>
                    </Grid>
                  </Typography>
                </TableCell>
                <TableCell align="right">{'<<Placement value>>'}</TableCell>
              </TableRow>
            ))}
          </TableBody>
```

I just created a demo in a sandbox to show you but the strange thing is that it works correctly there but not in my app.

The full code is in my Gist: https://gist.github.com/SerdarMustafa1/b3214b01885980e433405987f8822fe7

and demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/5dm8lk?file=demo.js.

Any ideas what's gone wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use array of states to keep the state of each raw:

```
import React, {useState} from "react";
import { withStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import { purple } from "@material-ui/core/colors";
import FormGroup from "@material-ui/core/FormGroup";
import FormControlLabel from "@material-ui/core/FormControlLabel";
import Switch from "@material-ui/core/Switch";
import Grid from "@material-ui/core/Grid";
import Table from "@material-ui/core/Table";
import TableBody from "@material-ui/core/TableBody";
import TableCell from "@material-ui/core/TableCell";
import TableContainer from "@material-ui/core/TableContainer";
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import TableHead from "@material-ui/core/TableHead";
import TableRow from "@material-ui/core/TableRow";
import Paper from "@material-ui/core/Paper";
import { makeStyles, withStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";


const AntSwitch = withStyles(theme => ({
  root: {
    width: 28,
    height: 16,
    padding: 0,
    display: "flex"
  },
  switchBase: {
    padding: 2,
    color: theme.palette.grey[500],
    "&$checked": {
      transform: "translateX(12px)",
      color: theme.palette.common.white,
      "& + $track": {
        opacity: 1,
        backgroundColor: theme.palette.primary.main,
        borderColor: theme.palette.primary.main
      }
    }
  },
  thumb: {
    width: 12,
    height: 12,
    boxShadow: "none"
  },
  track: {
    border: `1px solid ${theme.palette.grey[500]}`,
    borderRadius: 16 / 2,
    opacity: 1,
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.common.white
  },
  checked: {}
}))(Switch);

const tableStyles = makeStyles({
  table: {
    minWidth: 150
  }
});

export default function CustomizedSwitches() {
  const [gridData, setGridData] = useState([
    { key: 6, operator: "OyPohjolanLiikenne Ab", checked: false },
    { key: 12, operator: "Helsingin Bussiliikenne Oy", checked: true },
    { key: 17, operator: "Tammelundin Liikenne Oy", checked: false },
    { key: 18, operator: "Pohjolan Kaupunkiliikenne Oy", checked: true },
    { key: 20, operator: "Bus Travel Åbergin Linja Oy", checked: false },
    { key: 21, operator: "Bus Travel Oy Reissu Ruoti", checked: true }
  ]);

  const handleChange = (event, index) => {
    gridData[index].checked = event.target.checked;
    setGridData([...gridData]);
  };

  const tableClasses = tableStyles();


  return (
    <TableContainer component={Paper}>
      <Table
        stickyHeader
        className={tableClasses.table}
        size="small"
        aria-label="a dense table"
      >
        <TableHead>
          <TableRow>
            <TableCell>Operator</TableCell>
            {/* <TableCell align="right">Listed</TableCell> */}
            <TableCell>Visible</TableCell>
            <TableCell align="right">Total Placements</TableCell>
          </TableRow>
        </TableHead>
        <TableBody>
          {gridData.map( (row, index) => (
            <TableRow key={row.key}>
              <TableCell component="th" scope="row">
                {row.operator}
              </TableCell>
              <TableCell>
                <Typography component="div">
                  <Grid
                    component="label"
                    container
                    alignItems="center"
                    // justify="flex-end"
                    spacing={1}
                  >
                    <Grid item>Off</Grid>
                    <Grid item>
                      <AntSwitch
                        checked={row.checked}
                        onChange={(event) => handleChange(event, index)}
                        name="checkedC"
                      />
                    </Grid>
                    <Grid item>On</Grid>
                  </Grid>
                </Typography>
              </TableCell>
              <TableCell align="right">{"<<Placement value>>"}</TableCell>
            </TableRow>
          ))}
        </TableBody>
      </Table>
    </TableContainer>
  );
}
```

Comment: `gridData[index].checked = event.target.checked;` is a ***state mutation***, better to use a functional update to shallow copy existing state and update the element matching index, i.e. `const { checked } = event.target; setGridData(gridData => gridData.map((item, i) => i === index ? { ...item, checked } : item));`.

Comment: Have adjusted accordingly. Thanks to both.

Answer (score 0):

Combining Arthur Ruben's answer and Drew Reese's comment.

Here's how I assigned props to a switch state array to be used by the switch and update fields inside the grid depending on the state of that switch.

Each row inside table needs its own state (and each column, as well, if you want to change columns within rows). You can monitor state of different switches as well as change fileds inside the row this way.

```js
export default function TableComponent(props) {
  const { rows } = props;
  // generate array from incoming props,
  // to be assigned to the state of this components
  let stateInitArray = rows.map((row, index) => ({
    id: index,
    checked: false,
    transactionType: "Session",
  }));

  const [gridState, setGridState] = React.useState(stateInitArray);
  const handleSwitchChange = (event, index) => {
    const { checked } = event.target;
    let transactionType = checked ? "Payment" : "Session";
    setGridState((prevState) =>
      prevState.map((row, i) =>
        // iterate over the state and update value of row where the switch was pressed
        i === index ? { ...row, checked, transactionType } : row
      )
    );
  };
  return (
    <TableContainer component={Paper}>
      <Table sx={{ minWidth: 650 }} size="small" aria-label="a dense table">
        <TableHead>
          <TableRow>
            <TableCell align="left">isPayment?</TableCell>
            <TableCell>Date</TableCell>
            <TableCell align="left">Cost</TableCell>
            <TableCell align="left">Transaction Type</TableCell>
            <TableCell align="left">Column Gap</TableCell>
            <TableCell align="left">Column Gap</TableCell>
            <TableCell align="left">Column Gap</TableCell>
            <TableCell align="left">Message</TableCell>
          </TableRow>
        </TableHead>
        <TableBody>
          {rows.map((row, index) => (
            <TableRow
              key={row.name}
              sx={{ "&:last-child td, &:last-child th": { border: 0 } }}
            >
              <TableCell>
                <Switch
                  key={gridState[index].id}
                  checked={gridState[index].checked}
                  onChange={(event) => {
                    handleSwitchChange(event, index);
                  }}
                  inputProps={{ "aria-label": "controlled" }}
                />
              </TableCell>
              <TableCell component="th" scope="row">
                {row.date}
              </TableCell>
              <TableCell align="left">
                {gridState[index].transactionType === "Payment" ? "" : row.cost}
              </TableCell>
              <TableCell align="left">
                {gridState[index].transactionType}
              </TableCell>
              <TableCell align="left"></TableCell>
              <TableCell align="left"></TableCell>
              <TableCell align="left"></TableCell>
              <TableCell align="left">{row.message}</TableCell>
            </TableRow>
          ))}
        </TableBody>
      </Table>
    </TableContainer>
  );
}
```